# How do I pass a variable to request's callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I'm using express and request to turn a site's html into json, then returning it. For example:

```
app.get('/live', function(req,_res){
  res = _res;
  options.url = 'http://targetsite.com';
  request(options,parseLive);
});

function parseLive(err, resp, html) {
  var ret = {status:'ok'};
  -- error checking and parsing of html --
  res.send(ret);
}
```

Currently I'm using a global var res to keep track of the return call, but this fails when multiple requests are made at the same time. So, I need some way of matching return calls from express to their callbacks in request.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure.

Pass the variable to a function. Return the function you want to pass to `request` from that function.

```
app.get('/live', function(req,_res){
  options.url = 'http://targetsite.com';
  request(options,parseLiveFactory(res));
});


function parseLiveFactory(res) {
    function parseLive(err, resp, html) {
      var ret = {status:'ok'};
      -- error checking and parsing of html --
      res.send(ret);
    }
    return parseLive;
}
```

Comment: I've been pounding my head against this for a while. Seeing how easy that was makes me feel silly. Alas, thank you!